# Delayed entry survival model: R vs Stata differences

Tags: r, stata, survival-analysis

I have some code in Stata that I'm trying to redo in R. I'm working on a delayed entry survival model and I want to limit the follow-up to 5 years. In Stata this is very easy and can be done as follows for example:

```
stset end, fail(failure) id(ID) origin(start) enter(entry) exit(time 5)
stcox var1
```

However, I'm having trouble recreating this in R. I've made a toy example limiting follow-up to 1000 days - here is the setup:

```
library(survival); library(foreign); library(rstpm2)

data(brcancer)
brcancer$start <- 0
# Make delayed entry time
brcancer$entry <- brcancer$rectime / 2
# Write to dta file for Stata
write.dta(brcancer, "brcancer.dta")
```

Ok so now we've set up an identical dataset for use in both R and Stata. Here is the Stata bit code and model result:

```
use "brcancer.dta", clear
stset rectime, fail(censrec) origin(start) enter(entry) exit(time 1000)
stcox hormon
```

[image]

And here is the R code and results:

```
# Limit follow-up to 1000 days
brcancer$limit <- ifelse(brcancer$rectime <1000, brcancer$rectime, 1000)
# Cox model 
mod1 <- coxph(Surv(time=entry, time2= limit, event = censrec) ~ hormon, data=brcancer, ties = "breslow")
summary(mod1)
```

[image]

As you can see the R estimates and Stata estimates differ slightly, and I cannot figure out why. Have I set up the R model incorrectly to match Stata, or is there another reason the results differ?

Comment: As it stands the possibility that this is reproducible lies in the answer to the question: Where does `brcancer` come from? I also think that you should have changed any of the deaths at time greater than 1000 to be considered censored. (Notice that the numbers of events is quite different in the two sets of results.

Comment: `brcancer` is a dataset in the rstpm2 package (that is why I loaded that package). It is also a Stata dataset, however I saved it to file then loaded it into Stata to show it is the same data. Good observation about the number of events. I've just generated a new censor variable: `brcancer$fail <- ifelse(brcancer$rectime < 1000, brcancer$censrec, 0)` and now both models match. Oddly this didn't work before in real data, maybe I made some error. thank you - I think this solves my problem

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. (Sorry for not reading your question more closely.) Then you can get upvotes and the unanswered question queue can be reduced. Upvoting your question, but I suggest you add the comment material using [edit] since that is the recommended strategy for clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the methods match on an avaialble dataset after recoding the deaths that occur after to termination date, I'm posting the relevant sections of my comment as an answer.

> I also think that you should have changed any of the deaths at time greater than 1000 to be considered censored. (Notice that the numbers of events is quite different in the two sets of results.

Comment: That's great thanks 42. I've now rectified this in my real data too so I'm happy. Thanks for your help